# Debounce in Combine Stop Publishing

Tags: swift, combine

Here is my code. If i remove/commment out debounce, it works. Not sure why?

```
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .debounce(for: .milliseconds(500), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .map {
                $0.data
            }
            .decode(type: [Course].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .replaceError(with: [])
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .print()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .sink(receiveValue: { posts in
                self.courses = posts
            })
            .store(in: &bag)
```

Comment: Why do you think you need `debounce` here?

Comment: for example to limit user tap action which calls above codes

Comment: That wouldn't stop the http request from being made though. You'd probably want to debounce the user tap action itself, before invoking `URLSession`